# Linq: using let statement based on string to group data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, aggregate

Here´s my scenario...

Supposing i have this class (called nf) w/values:

```
MyDate,Tons,ClientCode
25/12/2020,10,A
26/12/2020,5,A
27/12/2020,5,A
14/12/2020,7,A
11/12/2020,3,A
```

So i wrote the following code to get results grouped.

```
   List<HC> nfs = (from n in ctx.nf
                   where n.ClientCode.StartsWith(CLIENT_CODE_STR)
                   let quinzena = $"{n.MyDate.Year}/{n.MyDate.Month}/{(n.DataEmissao.Day >= 1 && n.MyDate.Day <= 15 ? "1QZ" : "2QZ")}"
                   group n by new { quinzena } into g
                   select new { qnz = g.Key.quinzena, totalc = g.Sum(x => x.Tons) }
                  ).Take(12)
                  .OrderByDescending(a => a.qnz)
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(r=> new HC{ Period = r.qnz, TotalTons = r.totalc }).ToList();
```

The expected result is:

```
Period,TotalTons
2020/12/1QZ,10
2020/12/2QZ,20
```

The point is the let statement... which is used to group data properly...
When the code runs I get this error...

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there a way to perform this grouping??
thx a lot

Comment: Your _`$"{n.MyDate.Year}/{n.MyDate.Month}/{(n.DataEmissao.Day >= 1 && n.MyDate.Day <= 15 ? "1QZ" : "2QZ")}"`_ interpolated string will be replaced in a `string.Format()`. The string.format is not supported by _your_ IQueryable handler, which creates the request/sql statement. Did you try to just concat it the old way?

Comment: Yeah... I tried... with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep those values separate until you need to combine them in memory.

```
List<HC> nfs = (from n in ctx.nf
               where n.ClientCode.StartsWith(CLIENT_CODE_STR)
               let q = n.DataEmissao.Day >= 1 && n.MyDate.Day <= 15 ? "1QZ" : "2QZ"
               group n by new { n.MayDate.Year, n.MayDate.Month, Q = q } into g
               select new { qnz = g.Key, totalc = g.Sum(x => x.Tons) }
              ).Take(12)
              .OrderByDescending(a => a.qnz.Year)
              .ThenByDescending(a => a.qnz.Month)
              .ThenByDescending(a => a.qnz.Q)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(r=> new HC
              { 
                  Period = $"{r.qnzYear}/{r.qnz.Month}/{r.qnz.Q}", 
                  TotalTons = r.totalc 
              })
              .ToList();
```